# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, illegalstateexception

I keep getting this exception while I'm trying to save an object to an H2 database.

The object I'm trying to persist is defined as following:

```
package mypackage.foo.core.jpa.domain;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
```

**The controller:**

```
package mypackage.foo.core.web.controller;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TaskController {

    private final TaskService taskService;

    @PostMapping("/api/task/save")
    public ResponseEntity<Task> handlePostAddTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        Task savedTask = taskService.save(task);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedTask, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**The payload that I'm sending to that endpoint via Postman:**

```
{
    "name":"first task",
    "description":"some fascinating description"
}
```

**The repository:**

```
package mypackage.foo.core.jpa.repository;

@Repository
public interface TaskDao extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
}
```

**The app configuration:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"mypackage.foo.core.jpa.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"mypackage.foo.core.jpa.domain"})
public class FooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Maven deps:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**My approach:**
The first idea was that it's been happening due to missing setter for `Id` in `Task`, but it didn't help. I've been wondering if I can get any hints how to solve this issue? 
Any attempt to call `save(task)` is causing `IllegalStateException` to be thrown.

The `save(Task task)` in `TaskService` is essentially calling the `taskDao.save(Task task)`.

I was also suspecting the wrong `@Id` annotation (I mean from the wrong package), but it's not the case here.

Comment: you have the h2 console where you can check how your table looks like. You will get more info for debug (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) . Also, have you just for test tried the GenerationType.AUTO instead of IDENTITY?

Comment: Just to verify, you are using `javax.persistence.Id` right?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, that's right

Comment: @Carlos changing to AUTO is causing different error:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO task (id, name, description, date_created, date_last_updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Basically the same issue, but with a different descirption

Comment: Try making a basic test for example removing all the lombok stuff and generating all the getters and setters manually on that class. Might be related to the visibility of your field.

Comment: @Carlos replacing Lombok stuff with generated getters/setters didn't help.

Comment: Since Hibernate accesses fields perfectly well without getters/setters, those wouldn't affect anything here.

Comment: Ok, so what would be the path forward from here? Do you guys have any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnes out that removing these two lines have helped:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"mypackage.foo.core.jpa.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"mypackage.foo.core.jpa.domain"})
```

When I noticed the same experience after switching to MySql, I started to think that the problem must be with my configuration. I tried to replace these annotations with `ComponentScan`, but IntelliJ started complaining that:
`Redundant declaration: @SpringBootApplication already applies given @ComponentScan`

so, my idea was, maybe these `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` aren't necessary here after all? Removing them helped. I'm not sure why tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use @Data annotation from lombok as given below. This will generate both setter & getter methods. I hope this will resolve the issue. 

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


@Data Equivalent to @Getter @Setter @RequiredArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode.

~Satheesh
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Satheesh Mekala How would this solve the issue, since I already have `@Getter` and `@Setter`? Besides, an entity shouldn't have setters for all fields by default and as far as constructors are concerned- Hibernate requires @NoArgsConstructor only.